# Visual Studio C# Windows Form project files disappears

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, windows-forms-designer

I've created one simple Windows form project on visual studio code, with .NET 5.0.
At the first launch of visual studio, the project worked well and I could debug it.
But now, when I try to lunch a debug, I have this error:

[image: The debug error]

This is the third time I re-made my application because the files in "AppContact\AppContact\bin\Debug\net5.0-windows" disappear each time I launch my project.

I've searched for my problem, but the only answer was "Check in the properties of the app, in the debug section" but not why the files always disappear.

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It's possible that an anti-virus program is silently removing files. For the major anti-virus programs they can allow folders to be excluded for being seen as a threat to the system.

Also, consider using Windows explorer, traverse to the folder and run the executable, does it get removed? If not then still with explorer open run from Visual Studio see what happens.

Comment: Yes, ther is nothing in the repository wich the files are supposed to be...
I don't have any anti-virus, so it can't be that.
I will check. Thanks

Comment: If running Windows 10, Defender is installed and could be the problem. Note there is nothing inside of Visual Studio that deletes files other than when a clean operation is done in a project or the solution.

Comment: Ok, Indeed it could be the problem, I will see more in detail of windows defender

Comment: Please keep us posted!